# Can I access the geoNear functionality of mongo via the node driver?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

something like?

```
db.open (err, client) -> 
    db.collection 'test', (err, collection) -> 
        collection.runCommand {geoNear:"loc", near:[50,50], $maxDistance:1}, #callback here?
```

Comment: Apparently you can do this, but the syntax from your question is in coffescript: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/656d60c6d14d3f73?pli=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using node-mongodb-native v0.9.3

It does have support for geoNear.

Use this command:

```
db.executeDbCommand({ geoNear : "CollectionName", near : [lat,lng], maxDistance : 10 }, function(err, result { // do something with results here});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding this too but I have just be using, `db.command({geoNear: 'collection'......`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/node-mongodb-native/browse_thread/thread/a2bf86975463f97c), the node driver has not implemented support for `geoNear`. However, the good news is that post provides a possible implementation, so you may be able to use that code to implement `geoNear` for your project.